# Default grok patterns path

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have installed Logstash on Ubuntu Server 14. 
Where can I find the default grok patterns that Logstash uses when filtering logs ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I have also installed ELK stack on Ubuntu 14.04. The location of patterns that grok uses is in the following directory

**/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-2.0.5/patterns/**

which includes the following default patterns

```
aws                   firewalls             junos                 mongodb               rails
bacula                grok-patterns         linux-syslog          nagios                redis
bro                   haproxy               mcollective           output.txt            ruby
exim                  java                  mcollective-patterns  postgresql            test.sh
```

Or you can just search for the patterns as follows:

## find / -name patterns

This will show you the directory of patterns you are looking for.

Comment: For faster searching for a directory, you can use `find / -type d -name patterns`

Answer (score 6):

From the [grok documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html):

```
Logstash ships with about 120 patterns by default. You can find them here:
```

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns.

Comment: I think what he means is, where do this patterns is located in the host where logstash is installed.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the logstash installation path, say `cd /usr/share/logstash/`

it is here:

`cd /vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.1.2/patterns/`

If installed via apt-get, to `/usr/share/logstash/` it is here:

`/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.1.2/patterns/`